# .pgpass for PostgreSQL replication in Dockerized environment

Tags: postgresql, docker, coreos

I try to set up an PostgreSQL slave using Docker and a bash script (I use Coreos). I have not found any way to supply a valid `.pgpass`.

I know I could create a PGPASSWORD environment variable, but do not wish to do so for security reasons (as stated here, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html),, and because this password should be accessible every time the recovery.conf file is used (for the primary_conninfo variable).

Dockerfile

```
# ...
# apt-get installs and other config
# ...

USER postgres
# Create role and db
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER replicator WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'THEPASSWORD';" &&\
    psql --command "CREATE DATABASE db WITH OWNER replicator;"

# Set the pg_pass to allow connection to master
ADD ./pgpass.conf /home/postgres/.pgpass # pgpass.conf comes my root git folder
USER root
RUN chmod 0600 /home/postgres/.pgpass
```

In my bash file

```
# ...

pg_basebackup -h host.of.master.ip -D /var/pgbackup/backup_data -U replicator -v -P

# ...
```

The problems seems to be that the pgpass file is not read. It seems I should use the password of the user I'm sudoing to (https://serverfault.com/questions/526170/psql-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied), but in this case the replicator role is naturally not an available bash user. (Note that neither copying the pgpass to /home/root not /home/postgres works).

Note: my pgpass file and by remote database conf

```
# pgpass.conf
host.of.master.ip:5432:replication:replicator:THEPASSWORD
host.of.master.ip:5432:*:replicator:THEPASSWORD

# pg_hba.conf
host    replication   replicator    host.of.slave.ip/24    md5
```

Comment: Have your tried setting PGPASSFILE?

Comment: Yes I tried export PGPASSFILE = /root/to/pgpass

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it? Working on the same issue now..

Comment: Hi @Justin. I ended up doing it by precising the full path PGPASSFILE=/home/postgres/pgpass pg_basebackup -x etc. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to create a `.pgpass` on the home folder of the user who's going to be running the commands (in this case, `postgres`). Each line of the file has to be in the [format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) `hostname:port:database:username:password` and supports wildcards, so you can just set the database to "*" for example.

In my case, I have something like this...

```
$ sudo echo "${PRIMARY_IP}:5432:*:${REPL_USER}:${REPL_PASS}" > /var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass
$ sudo chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass
$ sudo chmod 0600 /var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass
$ sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -h $PRIMARY_IP -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -U ${REPL_USER} -v -P --xlog-method=stream
```

Those variables (e.g. PRIMARY_IP) are set when I run the docker container with `-e PRIMARY_IP=x.x.x.x`

Comment: * in the database name certainly solved my docker implementation. Thanks!