# postgres pg_basebackup can't find .pg_pass file

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have successfully setup replication streaming from a primary to a secondary postgres docker container, each running as tasks on separate ec2 instances.
However, I did this by leaving the *replication* user on the primary server as *trust*  in its pg_hba.conf:

`host  replication replication 0.0.0.0/0 trust`

Then, when I switched it to md5, I thought I would be able to simply set a password on the secondary for the replication user and everything would be fine.  Nope.

In my initialization script on the secondary, when I call

`pg_basebackup -h #{primary_ip} -p 5432 -D $PGDATA -U #{repl_user} -v -P -w --xlog-method=stream`

I initially got the password prompt.
Then I added the `-w`. Which would give me the error:

`pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Then I found out there is no *postgres* home directory on the generic postgres 9.6 image, so I added a $PG_PASSFILE variable. That didn't work (Permissions were fine, I even put it in /tmp as well as passed the PG_PASSFILE=... right on the pg_basebackup line as in this question: [.pgpass for PostgreSQL replication in Dockerized environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388078/pgpass-for-postgresql-replication-in-dockerized-environment/35835804#35835804) (see Raphael's comment))
No matter what I do, the pg_basebackup ignores the .pg_pass file.

I then tried mounting a volume as /home/postgres but with AWS, I can't seem to gosu to root inside the entry point init script I have created.  Everything is as the *postgres* user.

Has anybody overcome this?
I am running my secondary initialization code as an entrypoint script.  Like I said, it works fine as *trust* but adding that password is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

If you set replication you dont need to run `pg_basebackup` any more. adding `-w` will always give you `fe_sendauth: no password supplied` if you set anything but `trust` or `peer` for local to corresponding connection - just because `-w` stands for `--no-password`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html

> PGPASSFILE specifies the name of the password file to use for lookups.
>   If not set, it defaults to ~/.pgpass (see Section 32.15).

so default is `.pgpass`, not `.pg_pass`, of course you can use `.pg_pass`, setting `export PGPASSFILE=.pg_pass` , but you use `PG_PASSFILE` variable - right?..

So postgres ignores it, and it should.

I would first try creating right `.pgpass` in home directory with `600` permissions.

Also mind different `primary_conninfo` if you want to use password file. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/standby-settings.html

> in a separate ~/.pgpass file on the standby server (use replication as
>   the database name). Do not specify a database name in the
>   primary_conninfo string.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  Since I am running in a script, I need the -w for it not to attempt to prompt me.  It then looks for the .pgpass file.  On the AWS EC2 instance, postgres does not have a home directory, and I can't create one because I don't have sudo in the script.  Even when I set PG_PASSFILE env var on the command line, it wont use it. It has something to do with the AWS/EC2/Docker environment, I believe.

Comment: Also, I am not sure how to do it without the pg_basebackup.  I will look into that.

Comment: I ended up changing my strategy slightly: I created my own docker image from postgres and creating the home directory and setting the permissions myself.  Then, in the postgres entrypoint init script, I just echo'd  the values for the .pgpass file into it.  It works fine now.